# Windows 7 updating every time I shut down my PC

Tags: windows, updates

In the last few days, every night when I turn off my PC, there is an update installed (1). In the windows updater, it says that it's an "update for windows 7 for x64-systems" (translated word for word from german). Does anyone know if this is normal?

Comment: Is it always the exact same update that's offered?  Have you tried [resetting your Windows Update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058) yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because of your "Windows Update" settings. If it is configured to run frequently (daily), then the available updates downloaded in the temp location and will get installed when you shutting down your machine.

Configure the "Windows Update" settings as per your convenient time window and ensure your other processes not delayed because of frequent updates.

Go to Control Panel > Windows Update > Change Settings > now, change your selection from the drop down box.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Start Run Type "services.msc"
- In the window that opens (Services), look for the following entry in the the right pane:
         **"Windows Update"**
- Double click on this entry. 
  see the below image
  [image]
- In the windows that opens first "Stop" the service.
- Set Startup type as "Disabled".
- Click on Ok to validate.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same thing;  like you i didn't think it was 'normal' and that maybe the update installation was failing for some reason, then repeating itself the next time i shut down. You can monitor the updates through Start/All Programs/Windows Update, then select 'view history'. When i ddi this i could see there were a whole lot of updates (all successful) then, next day, a whole lot of different updates, also all successful. Seems a bit weird to me, but not too worried ....yet

Comment: ..as an update, I have now had 5 consecutive days of Windows updates, all different, all apparently valid - but totally unprecedented at this volume and frequency.